# How to read specific values in string?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, TOMILA RELEASE V6.24 , i want to get 6.24 i used

```
 if (txt.Contains("<TOMILA RELEASE")) 
 {
     int iStartIndex = txt.LastIndexOf("<TOMILA RELEASE") + 17;
     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
         if (txt[iStartIndex + i] == '>') break;
         currentRelease += txt[iStartIndex + i];

     }
 }
```

So, my question is if i want to get the specific 6 from TOMILA RELEASE V6.24, how could i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `LastIndexOf` followed by `Substring`

```
var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('TOMILA RELEASE V') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take first number in the string you can use following regular expression.

```
string s = "TOMILA RELEASE V6.24";
string digit = Regex.Match(s, "\\d").Value;
```

Here \d is for matching the digit, you can find more about regular expression in this tutorial, [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

If you want to extract all number before dot then you can add + with \d and use do to end the extraction.

```
string number = Regex.Match(s, "\\d+.").Value.Replace(".","");
```

Comment: What does "\\d" means?

Comment: \d is for matching the digit, the tutorial will help you understand, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a specific portion of a string, you could use the below code

```
  string str = "6.24";
  var val = str.Substring(0, 1);
```